# Is the square of a hermitian operator hermitian?

Tags: linear-algebra

If $\hat{O}$ is hermitian, what I see is that
$$(\psi,\hat{O}\phi) = (\hat{O} \psi,\phi)$$
Therefore,
$$(\psi,\hat{O}^2\phi)=(\hat{O}\psi,\hat{O}\phi)=(\hat{O}^2\psi,\phi)$$
Therefore the answer to my question seems to be yes. But I have in a quantum mechanics book a question asking to prove the opposite. What is wrong?

Comment: According to usual definitions, the square of a hermitian operator is indeed hermitian.  Could you post the precise statement from the book you are looking at, along with any relevant definitions?

Comment: Well, it turned out that the $\hat{O}$ that I am talking about is hermitian only for vectors that satisfy certain conditions, and that for some vector $\psi$, $\hat{O}\psi$ does not satisfy these conditions.

Comment: More precisely, for those who are physicists, my operator is the momentum operator, and the vector which made me puzzled is hydrogen  state vectors of l=0.